# Is anyone using Karate for Salesforce API testing?

Tags: karate

Is anyone using Karate for Salesforce API testing?
I haven't seen any examples related to accessing Salesforce Rest API. On our team we do lot of work with Salesforce APIs.

Comment: I don't understand why you have to ask this question. what's so special about salesforce. karate handles any kind of HTTP service (rest, soap, graphql) and there are plenty of examples. what more do you need ?